# html/javascript - input/text to image on page load

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to HTML and javascripts. I hope someone can help me with my issue.
I am generating a code and passing the value to a textbox, then convert that value to a image. I need to execute the two function on page load is it possible? I hope someone can help. Thanks a lot!

Here is my code:

```js
function SecurityCode() {                                                                                                    
    //Generate security code and assign to 'text'
    document.getElementById('text').value = GeneratedCode; 
}

function TexttoImage(){
    // found this code here , thanks Stackoverflow! 
    var tCtx = document.getElementById('textCanvas').getContext('2d'),
    imageElem = document.getElementById('image');
    
    document.getElementById('text').addEventListener('onload', function (){
        tCtx.canvas.width = tCtx.measureText(this.value).width;
        tCtx.fillText(this.value, 0, 10);
        imageElem.src = tCtx.canvas.toDataURL();
        console.log(imageElem.src);
    }, false);
}
```

```html
<body onload='TexttoImage();'>
    <canvas id='textCanvas' width='65' height='42'></canvas>
    <img id='image' width='65' height='42'>  
    <input type='text' id='text' >
</body>
```

Comment: onload='SecurityCode();'

Comment: onload='SecurityCode(); TexttoImage();'

Comment: Also, dont add event listener inside a function, its not a good practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make an init function who regroup all functions than you whan to charge on load

```
function SecurityCode() {                                                                                                    
//Generate security code and assign to 'text'
document.getElementById('text').value = GeneratedCode;  
}

function TexttoImage(){
    // found this code here , thanks Stackoverflow! 
    var tCtx = document.getElementById('textCanvas').getContext('2d'),
    imageElem = document.getElementById('image');

    document.getElementById('text').addEventListener('onload', function (){
        tCtx.canvas.width = tCtx.measureText(this.value).width;
        tCtx.fillText(this.value, 0, 10);
        imageElem.src = tCtx.canvas.toDataURL();
        console.log(imageElem.src);
    }, false);
} 

function initFormOnLoad(){
    SecurityCode();
    TexttoImage();
}
```

And in your form

```
<body onload='initFormOnLoad();'>
    <canvas id='textCanvas' width='65' height='42'></canvas>
    <img id='image' width='65' height='42'>  
    <input type='text' id='text' >
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `onload` attribute takes a string of JavaScript code, so you can simply put the two functions together!

```
onload="TexttoImage(); SecurityCode()"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using jquery to ease your problem, you will need to include the below to your html page

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
```

HTML -

```
<body>
    <canvas id='textCanvas' width='65' height='42'>
    <img id='image' width='65' height='42' /></canvas>
    <input type='text' id='text' />
</body>
```

javascript -

```
   function SecurityCode() {
       //Generate security code and assign to 'text'
       document.getElementById('text').value = "hello1"; //GeneratedCode;
   }

   function TexttoImage() {
       // found this code here , thanks Stackoverflow! 
       var tCtx = document.getElementById('textCanvas').getContext('2d');
       imageElem = document.getElementById('image');
       tCtx.canvas.width = tCtx.measureText(document.getElementById('text').value).width;
       tCtx.fillText(document.getElementById('text').value, 0, 10);
       imageElem.src = tCtx.canvas.toDataURL();
   }
   $(function() { // nearly equivalent to body.onload but a better option to use
       SecurityCode();
       TexttoImage();
   })
```

Have a look at [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f8nyxyzm/1/) for working code.